# Auto update script for Valheim server on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a server for the game Valheim running as a service headless in ubuntu. It will run automatically when the appropriate user logs in.

However, I have run into a slight problem. Any time the client game updates the server needs to be up to date, less they are denied a connection.
While I have seen sudo crontab updates for the system its self, I don't know how to set up a service to update the game. currently, I have 3 minimum commands to update the client.

1. sudo systemctl stop valheim
2. /home/username/.steam/steamcmd/steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir
   /home/username/Valheim +app_update 896660 validate +exit
3. sudo systemctl stop valheim

Is there a way to make an auto-run file to do this with sudo password? Bonus points if this option could be launched remotely if I'm not at home to run the file.

Answer (score 2):

I am hosting a valheim server for a friend of mine on my dedicated server (Debian 10) and ran into the same issue you did. I created a bash script to update the server automatically.

Place this script within any folder you want to have it inside. I preferred to put it in the valheim directory. Then change the values inside the script to correspond to your environment.

Then execute "chmod +x [script path]" to make it executable.

Then create an entry within your /etc/crontab file looking like this (this will update the server at 4AM every day (change the 4 to anything else if you want to). Don't forget to use the correct script path.

```
0  4    * * *   root    /home/steam/valheim/update_server.sh
```

Script (update_valheim.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash 

# BEGIN - EDIT THOSE LINES TO CORRESPOND TO YOUR ENVIRONMENT    
   
# Where should the update script log to?
LOGNAME="/var/log/valheim-update.log"

# Path of your steamcmd executable
STEAMCMD="/home/steam/steamcmd"

# Start timestamp - don't change this.
STA_TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"`

# Installation directory of your dedicated server
VALHEIM_INSTALL_DIRECTORY="/home/steam/valheim"

# Command to run after updating the server
VALHEIM_SERVICE_RESTART="service valheim restart"

# The user to execute the steamcmd with (to not run it as root preventing security issues)
VALHEIM_USER="steam"    

# END - THE REST SHOULDN'T BE EDITED    

printf '\n[*] %s - Updating valheim dedicated server via cronjob...\n\n' $STA_TIMESTAMP >> "$LOGNAME"   

# We prevent permission issues when this script is placed inside the valheim folder as root user. ;) 
chown -R $VALHEIM_USER $VALHEIM_INSTALL_DIRECTORY

su - $VALHEIM_USER -c "$STEAMCMD +login anonymous +force_install_dir $VALHEIM_INSTALL_DIRECTORY +app_update 896660 validate +exit" >> "$LOGNAME" 2>&1   

printf '\n[*] Restarting service...\n\n' >> "$LOGNAME"  

END_TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"`   

$VALHEIM_SERVICE_RESTART >> "$LOGNAME" 2>&1 

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        printf '\n[*] Service successfully restarted\n\n%s - Update succeeded\n' $END_TIMESTAMP >> "$LOGNAME"
else
        printf '\n[!] CRITICAL: Error while restarting the service (ERRORLEVEL does not equal ZERO)\n\n%s - Update failed\n' $END_TIMESTAMP >> "$LOGNAME"
fi
```

Kind regards from Germany and have fun

Thomas

--- EDIT ---

If you want to enable other people to execute the script if you aren't home you could use a PHP script on your webserver (if you got one) and add a sudo entry for the www-data user to execute the script as root aswell. Just don't forget to protect the corresponding link with a .htaccess file.

/etc/sudoers

```
 www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/steam/valheim/update_server.sh
```

PHP

```
<?php
set_time_limit(500);
shell_exec("/home/steam/valheim/update_server.sh");
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work with root crontab?

```
sudo crontab -e
```

the cron:

```
@hourly echo "yourpassword" | sudo myfile.sh
```

Your password will be exposed to anyone who has access to that cron though, not a huge deal but keep it in mind.